# PhoneGap app using both Media API and Web Audio API is muted when recording begins

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, phonegap-build, web-audio-api

So essentially, I have background sounds that play via the Web Audio API and their play function looks something like this:

```
 function playSound(buffer) {
    if (buffer) {
        var source = appAudioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(appAudioContext.destination);
        source.start(0);
    } else {
        alert("ERROR: playSound has undefined buffer");
    }
}
```

When I start recording with the PhoneGap Media API though (cordova-plugin-media via npm), all of my Web Audio sounds are muted and I can't play them even when recording is stopped. Is there a way to make these two APIs play well together in PhoneGap? I'm developing a sound-heavy application that will need the versatility of Web Audio API with the native recording features of the Media API.

Answer (score 2):

you have not stated which plugins you are using. I must assume you are using the phonegap *core* plugins. You need to use a third-party plugin. Here is your [search for audio](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=audio).

This is likely the plugin you want [cordova-plugin-deviceaudioservice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-deviceaudioservice). This plugin is made for iOS only - I assume this from your tags. If you need one for Android, you need to say so.

Lastly, that same plugin is available in the PGB repository under a [different name](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/745). However, since we are moving to NPM, I highly recommend you use the NPM version. If it is not clear to you - how use the NPM plugin, please write back.